# AJAX .js file not firing in HTML code

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm relatively new to JS, and I'm currently working on XMLHttpRequests and closures. My main goal is to (1) have all the xhr code on one .js file (2) pull it in to my index.html page via an src tag, and finally (3) call the xhr function on the index.html page.

The trouble comes when I try to do number 3... I'm able to call my function to trigger the xhr on its native .js file, but not in the index.html.

Here's what I've written so far:

```
var experiment = function(callback){

    return function(destination){

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.onload = function(){
            if(xhr.readyState === 4){
                if(xhr.status === 200){
                    var text = xhr.responseText;
                    callback(text);
                }

                else{
                    console.log(xhr.statusText);
                }

            }
        }


        xhr.open("get", destination, true);
        xhr.send(null);
    }
}

function closure(url){
    return experiment(alert)(url);
}
```

And then, in my index.html page, pull in something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="exp.js">

    closure("url.com/json");

</script>
```

But the XHR never fires. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you including the js file in the html file before the call to closure()?

Comment: Whoops! Good call! That did it. Thank you so much!! I can't believe I typed out that whole thing and didn't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="exp.js"/>
<script>

    closure("url.com/json");

</script>
```